# Memory error when updating user field with Rules

Tags: 8, users, rules, actions

I'm using the Rules module to update my user email signatures.

The rule get's triggered whenever an account is updated and performs a simple custom action.

This is the action, all it does is save a new value to the signature field (textfield, full_html).

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\frontview_general\Plugin\RulesAction;

use Drupal\rules\Core\RulesActionBase;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;

/**
 * Change event date status to ( selected, open, closed )
 *
 * @RulesAction(
 *   id = "rules_update_signature",
 *   label = @Translation("Update User Signature"),
 *   category = @Translation("Custom"),
 *   context_definitions = {
 *     "uid" = @ContextDefinition("integer",
 *       label = @Translation("User id"),
 *       description = @Translation("Specifies the id of the user that needs to be updated.")
 *     )
 *   }
 * )
 */
class UpdateSignature extends RulesActionBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function doExecute($uid) {

    $user = User::load($uid);

    $first_name = $user->get("field_first_name")->value;
    $last_name = $user->get("field_last_name")->value;

    $name = $first_name . " " . $last_name;

    $user->set("field_signature", $name);
    $user->field_signature->format = "full_html";

    $user->save();

  }
}
```

This all works fine until it hits the  `$user->save();` part. That's where something goes wrong and I end up with this error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /Users/lennertslabbinck/Sites/Frontview/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Cache/DatabaseBackend.php on line 167
```

This works great in other actions with other content so it probably has something to do with this being users but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Try this on the ->set line instead let me know if it works or not: `$user->set("field_signature", ['value' => $name, 'format' => 'full_html']);` (and remove the `$user->field_signature->format = "full_html";` line below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is loop update user infinity. When user update, hook_entity_update will be call:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_update().
 */
function rules_entity_update(EntityInterface $entity) {
  // Only handle content entities and ignore config entities.
  if ($entity instanceof ContentEntityInterface) {
    $entity_type_id = $entity->getEntityTypeId();
    $event = new EntityEvent($entity, [
      $entity_type_id => $entity,
      $entity_type_id . '_unchanged' => $entity->original,
    ]);
    $event_dispatcher = \Drupal::service('event_dispatcher');
    $event_dispatcher->dispatch("rules_entity_update:$entity_type_id", $event);
  }
}
```

[soure](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/rules/-/blob/8.x-3.x/rules.module#L174)

This event will be call your rule action. So when you call $user->save(), the hook_entity_update will call again... That's your problem. To be resolve, you can follow [example](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/rules/-/blob/8.x-3.x/src/Plugin/RulesAction/UserUnblock.php).

- Edit your annotation. "user" = @ContextDefinition("entity:user",
- Update logic method `doExecute`
- Update your rule.

**Remember don't call $user->save() again.**